# Error checking not being properly displayed

Tags: c, arrays, stack

After spending more than few days on debugging, I can't find the reason why my code below creates additional spaces when printing out the error check ("expecting or missing"). For example, when I run each of these line of symbols one at a time in order.

The first two works fine, but the third line of input will error check at the wrong position. But the symbol that its expecting is correct (<). When I remove the call to the reset function in the bottom of my code, the error check of the third line of input will be at the correct position but the symbol that its expecting is incorrect: { . Most likely because the stack hasn't reseted from the previous line of inputs.

I made print statements on the values of the increments for printing spaces and the size of the char array itself, but the numbers are correct. The culprit might be the reset function I made, but the character resets fine. Only problem is that the output is creating additional spaces when printing out the error check, which leads to displaying the error check at the wrong position.

Comment: Could you please post what language you're using in the tags?

Comment: Do you have a grammar? How do you know which kind of opening brace/bracket/paren you expect? It seems any one of them can occur at any nesting level inside any other.

Comment: When I run the code the third one works fine, at least it seems to flag the expected error. Perhaps you could clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Enter the first two lines first. Then the third line last. It will print the error check at the wrong position for the third line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `check1` and `check2` to `false` within your while loop. Other wise when running the third case after the second it includes extra white space resulting in the wrong offset.